# Background image full size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I will set a background image on the full size from browser. 
the scroll down site, the picture with normal scroll up.

watch the link: http://cnation.co

I have added this:

```
#header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/head.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 / cover ;
    font-size: 0.1px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

but that is not working
how can I do this?

Comment: You want to use `position: fixed`

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what you pretend. Please, describe it better

Comment: Everything looks right, your issue looks like your height, 100% doesn't mean the full height of the image, it means the full height of whichever div it is being contained in. If that div/body isn't specified with a height nothing will show.

Comment: I want the image 1: 1 readjust

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're saying, but maybe try in CSS:

```
#header {
/*your code here*/
background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zack is right. Use position: fixed. Also, instead of #header consider using an id like #background-image. Here's an example of what you could do.

```
#background-image {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/head.jpg") center cover;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;     
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: fix is not good. i will only the browser height. 1:1 on the link.

Comment: if you want the image to be square then make the width: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

Add background size in your CSS, and this will work on all browsers:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/head.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 / cover;
background-size: 100% auto;
```